# How do I freeze time and assert on a timestamp in a template?

Tags: python, django, django-unittest, freezegun

`p1/urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('t1/', views.t1),
]
```

`p1/views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def t1(request):
    return render(request, 'p1/t1.html')
```

`p1/templates/p1/t1.html`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root timestamp="{% now 'Y-m-d H:i:s' %}">...</root>
```

`p1/settings.py`:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tokyo'
USE_TZ = True
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'p1',
]
```

`p1/tests.py`:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from freezegun import freeze_time

class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    @freeze_time('2019-01-02 03:04:05')
    def test_freezegun(self):
        expected_response = '''
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <root timestamp="2019-01-02 03:04:05">...</root>
        '''
        response = self.client.get('/t1/')
        self.assertXMLEqual(expected_response, response.content.decode(response.charset))
```

Then,

```
$ ./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_freezegun (p1.tests.MyTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yuri/_/1/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/freezegun/api.py", line 658, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yuri/_/1/p1/p1/tests.py", line 12, in test_freezegun
    self.assertXMLEqual(expected_response, response.content.decode('utf-8'))
  File "/home/yuri/_/1/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 854, in assertXMLEqual
    self.fail(self._formatMessage(msg, standardMsg))
AssertionError: '\n            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n            <root timesta [truncated]... != '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<root timestamp="2019-01-02 12:04:05">. [truncated]...
- 
-             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
? ------------

+ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-             <root timestamp="2019-01-02 03:04:05">...</root>
? ------------                            ^^

+ <root timestamp="2019-01-02 12:04:05">...</root>
?                             ^^

-         

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.031s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

What am I doing wrong? Adding `tz_offset` to `freeze_time` doesn't help.

Comment: Did you tried checking utc, datetime, django now, values in shell ? I think timezone offset should work.

Comment: adding `tz_offset` to `freeze_time` should work, what do you mean by "doesn't help"?

Comment: I only remember that both expected and actual times kept changing as I changed `tz_offset`. Probably I had a wrong idea of how this all is going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing here is that most of the time Django stores timestamps in [UTC](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.1/django/utils/timezone.py#L230). And converts to local time only when presenting [data](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.1/django/template/defaulttags.py#L1150) to the [user](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.1/django/template/defaulttags.py#L374). So, the time I pass to `freeze_time` is treated as UTC, but then `now` in the template converts it to local time. As such, I've got to either specify local time in `expected_response` (`2019-01-02 12:04:05`), or time zone in "freeze time" string (`2019-01-02 03:04:05 JST`), or add `tz_offset` (JST is UTC+9h, so `tz_offset=-9`).